# Showing a Video Stream in specific bounds using Xamarin IOS

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, avcapturesession

I am writing a Xamarin ios app & I need to create a business card reader as shown in the image below. 
[image: Business Card Reader Design]

For this purpose I am using the following library 
https://github.com/xamarin/monotouch-samples/tree/master/MediaCapture

Following is the code I've in Xamarin IOS

```
 protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        page = e.NewElement as ScannerPage;
        page.BtnPropStart.Clicked += BtnPropStart_Clicked;
        page.BtnPropProcess.Clicked += BtnPropProcess_Clicked;


        imageView = new UIImageView(new CGRect((float)((NativeView.Bounds.Width - 400) / 2), (float)((NativeView.Bounds.Height - 200) / 2), 400, 200));
        imageView.ContentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFill;
        imageView.Image = UIImage.FromFile("scanner.png");
        imageView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.DarkGray;
        NativeView.AddSubview(imageView);                     

    }
```

When I click on the Scan button I see the Live stream from camera but it goes beyond the bounds of the sample image 
How can I show the camera stream within the guide markers (notice the 4 blue corners in the image below, need to show the stream within this) in a way that keeps the aspect ratio intact & does not transform the image in any way.

Any help in this regard is really appreciated.

Thanks 
ST

Comment: Recently I created a demo that might do what you are trying here. Maybe you want to give it a shot: https://github.com/Krumelur/RectangleDetection.iOS

Comment: Thanks @krumelur I am trying your solution now. Will update how it goes.

Comment: Hi @Krumelur your sample worked great. 

Since I need to write a Business card processing app, is there a way we can identify when we have the best image possible (best image is the one in which the details are clear enough to be sent for further image processing) in your imageViewPerspective control & when we have it we raise a flag so I can then save it & send it to our API for processing? 

Is this something we can do automatically or should we present a list of images to the end user & ask them to choose which one is best? 


Looking forward for your comment. 
Thanks

Comment: Difficult to answer. I'd say you need some further image processing to figure out the best one - but I have no idea how to do that.